# How to ping from a physical machine to another physical machine's VMware network VMnet8?

Tags: networking, local-area-network, vmware-workstation

I have a physical machine (first pm) which has VMware Workstation 14 Pro. By the configurations and settings I can ping among all the machines and any internet address from them as normally.

However, when I connect another physical machine (second pm) to first physical machine's network, it can't ping to the first physical machine's VMnet8 and other virtual machines on VMnet8 but it can ping to anywhere else on the internet. Interestingly, virtual machines and first physical machine can ping to the second physical machine.

By the way, all of the machines are enabled for in and out ping echos in firewall. After a bit view I discovered the second physical machine uses the first physical machine's default gateway only. I tried changing the second physical machine's default gateway as first physical machine's VMnet8 gateway but it didn't work. What can I do for this ?

Answer (score 0):

If I have well understood your problem, the second physical machine cannot ping the local network your created, which is expected.
VMWare create a virtual local-area-network inside your machine (VMnet8 in your case). By connecting the second physical machine, it's only connected to the first physical machine. So if it's gateway is the first physical machine, it should work. Otherwise, You need to have a routing solution in your first physical machine to connect to the second to the virtual network.

> I tried changing the second physical machine's default gateway as first physical machine's VMnet8 gateway but it didn't work

You can't do this as your network VMnet8 is virtual.

Comment: Looks good idea but how to implement routing in first physical machine?

Comment: Well, I have two solutions in mind :
1- Use a Virtual Router with two interfaces (deploy it in your VMware), one bridged so you can configure the gateway of the second virtual machine to that interface and one in the VMnet8. I've done this before, easy and efficace.
2- You can use a software in your machine that routes traffic (not a good solution but for test it answers the request), in Windows there is NAT32 and other solutions. If you are using Linux, it's easier,  many tools can respond to your demand.
(I wish I've been clear, sorry for my english)